# How to create a new custom property list in iPhone Applications

Tags: iphone

I want to create a new custom property list in iphone applications.How to create in and how to load in iphone class.

Answer (score 0):

Load:

```
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:kDefaultBookmarksPlistName
                            ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *defaultBookmarks = [[NSArray alloc]
                          initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

For saving, see the NSArray docs and look up `writeToFile`