# Write/Read plist file iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I have  plist in my iphone app and I want to read and write an integer from my single to and form it.

I have this to read it:

```
 scoreData *score = [scoreData sharedData];

 filePath = @"stats.plist";
 NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

 score.highScore = [plistDict objectForKey:@"score"];
```

Then to write to it:

```
scoreData *score = [scoreData sharedData];

 NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

 [plistDict setValue:score.highScore forKey:@"score"];
 [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
```

I am getting an error in both parts:

Invalid conversion form objc_object* to int

and

Invalid conversion form int to objc_object

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1. When you're setting a key in a dictionary, [you're probably after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutabl) `setObject:forKey:` instead of `setValue:forKey:`.
2. Dictionaries hold objects (type `id` or `NSString*` or your own Obj-C objects), not primitive types (int, BOOL, etc).

When you want to store a primitive type in an Obj-C collection, you can "wrap" it in an object like this:

```
[plistDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score.highScore] forKey:@"score"];
```

And get it back like this:

```
score.highScore = [[pListDict objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
```

Comment: Builds with no errors nw which is great! But I change score.highScore, then quit the app completely, relaunch and its back to zero, it never gets the value back. Would appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: Interesting discovery. I think the code I am using it writing to the plist and reading it but not actually saving it for when I next use the app. Possible? How can i get around this?

Comment: Probably it doesn't work because you are trying to write the dictionary to a .plist file inside your App bundle, which is read only. You should check the returned value of '[plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];' (YES=success, NO=write failed).

Try to write the file to a path in the App Bundle documents' folder, which is read-write. You can get the documents' path using: NSArray *arrayPaths = 
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
   NSDocumentDirectory,
   NSUserDomainMask,
   YES);

 NSString *docDir = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 0):

See if this answers your question:

[How to create a new custom property list in iPhone Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930205/how-to-create-a-new-custom-property-list-in-iphone-applications/3930258#3930258)

You could use NSUserDefaults but of course highScore isn't really a default.