# How to keep my data in a array-iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, database, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create an application, and in that I'm receiving some contents from net and loading into and array, if I quit and run the app again i'm losing the data. How can I store the data in the app itself. Should I use some kind of database? If so which one and how can I implement that? I need to store only some string variables.

**EDIT:**
My app is tabbar based app, and have two tabs. Loading the arrays in one tab and loading that array in a table in the other VC. once I load the array and move to the second tab, the table is loaded with the array. If i go back and add few more values and then if i check, the added datas is not displayed in the table. And also, when I quit the app the table lose all the values, I need to keep the values in the table, even after i quit the app. How can I do that?
here is my code:
in viewdidload:

```
 NSUserDefaults *simplePlistDb = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [simplePlistDb setBool:YES forKey:@"isItWorking"];
        [simplePlistDb setObject:alertList forKey:@"myArray"];
        [simplePlistDb synchronize];
```

in cellforrowatindexpath:-

```
NSUserDefaults *simplePlistDb = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL flag = [simplePlistDb boolForKey:@"isItWorking"];
    if (flag)
    {
        NSArray *myArray = [simplePlistDb objectForKey:@"myArray"];
        for (NSString *str in myArray){
            NSLog(@"Str:%@", str);
            [loadArray addObject:str];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [loadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your purposes `NSUserDefaults` will be enough : [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Examples:

```
// save
NSUserDefaults *simplePlistDb = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[simplePlistDb setBool:YES forKey:@"isItWorking"];
[simplePlistDb setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"very", @"cool", nil]];
[simplePlistDb synchronize];

// restore
NSUserDefaults *simplePlistDb = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL flag = [simplePlistDb boolForKey:@"isItWorking"];
if (flag)
{
    NSArray *myArray = [simplePlistDb objectForKey:@"myArray"];
    for (NSString *str in myArray)
        NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Comment: I need to load only string variables, so should I go for NSUserDefaults?

Comment: How much objects do you want to save?

Comment: that depends on the user, but mostly around 50. At maximum.

Comment: Then you can use `NSUserDefaults` or create your own `plist` file. The easiest way it to use `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: hi, is it possible to restore the stored strings into a tableview? how can I implement that?

Comment: i did and it is working, but there is problem. I have edited the main question. Please check it, and help. thanks.

Comment: After adding new data you should reload table: `[self.tableView reloadData];`. And of course you should manually save it.

Comment: still it is not working. I'm not able to see the new entry. :( here is my code: in ViewDidLoad- NSUserDefaults *simplePlistDb = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [simplePlistDb setBool:YES forKey:@"isItWorking"];
 NSArray *arrays = [[NSArray alloc]init];

 [simplePlistDb setObject:alertList forKey:@"myArray"];
 [simplePlistDb synchronize];

 [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: and in cellForRowAtIndexPath:- NSUserDefaults *simplePlistDb = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 BOOL flag = [simplePlistDb boolForKey:@"isItWorking"];
 if (flag)
 {
  NSArray *myArray = [simplePlistDb objectForKey:@"myArray"];
  for (NSString *str in myArray){
   NSLog(@"Str:%@", str);
   [loadArray addObject:str];
  }
  
 }
    cell.textLabel.text = [loadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
any idea??

Comment: Please, open new answer and describe problem there with your code. It's very difficult to view code in comments

Comment: Why would you have a for loop in the cellForRowAtIndex Method?!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look into Core Data if you want to save a decent amount of data to the iPhone. However, if not, you can just load the items in the array into a plist and load them from there at launch.

Plist Writing: [How to create a new custom property list in iPhone Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930205/how-to-create-a-new-custom-property-list-in-iphone-applications/3930258#3930258)

CoreData: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Edit--->

As Nekto said, you can also use NSUserDefaults, but I advise mainly using NSUserDefaults for simple NSStrings and integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSUserDefaults in order to store your data till the time your app is installed in your device.

#### How to write in NSuserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"yourObject1" forKey:@"correspopndingKey1"];
[defaults setObject:@"yourObject2" forKey:@"correspopndingKey2"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

#### How to read from NSuserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *temp1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"correspopndingKey1"];
NSString *temp2 = [defaults objectForKey:@"correspopndingKey2"];
```

You can store NSArray in a similar way.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:objArray forKey:@"correspopndingKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```